# VBA IE I need to click a embed button

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer

I have been trying to use

For Each MyHTML_Element In document.getElementsByTagName("embed")
If ele.Value = "ZeroClipboard_TableToolsMovie_1"then ele.Click

Code

```
embed id="ZeroClipboard_TableToolsMovie_1" align="middle" width="43" height="24" wmode="transparent" flashvars="id=1&width=43&height=24" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="false" allowscriptaccess="always" name="ZeroClipboard_TableToolsMovie_1" bgcolor="#ffffff" quality="best" menu="false" loop="false" src="/javascript/fc-andon-svc/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
```

Comment: you're not using this right, `getElementsByTagName` read properly how to use it, you need to supply a tag at least

Comment: Thank you, would the tag name be (embed id) ?

Comment: I would try "EMBED" first, but did you try getElementByID("ZeroClipboard_TableToolsMovie_1")?

Comment: I am not sure that you'll be able to get the embedded object and click a button within though.  That's the next challenge :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim element As Object
Set element = objIE.Document.getElementById("ZeroClipboard_TableToolsMovie_1")

If Not element Is Nothing Then
    element.Click
End if

Set element = Nothing
```

Comment: I think you need to have `element` as some sort of flash derivative.